# xsl copy-of return empty for child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

i have xml payload with this structure :

```
<tran:publish xmlns:tran="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/TransmissionService">
 <Transmission xmlns="">
  <TransmissionHeader>
  </TransmissionHeader>
  <TransmissionBody>
  </TransmissionBody>
</<Transmission>
</tran:publish>
```

i'm trying to copy the  tag with all i'ts child nodes as it's ,
and i'm using copy-of method , the problem is it returns empty

and this is the code for the xsl

```
 <ns59:echoAny xml:id="id_51">
   <ns59:xml xml:id="id_52">
     <xsl:copy-of xml:id="id_53" select="/nssrcmpr:publish/otm:Transmission"/>
   </ns59:xml>
 </ns59:echoAny>
```

but  if typed the /nssrcmpr:publish only  then it's copied as with all child values

what is the problem ?

Comment: Please show a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. We don't see your namespace declarations - and you are using a prefix for `Transmission` which in the input is no-namespace and should be selectable without a prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a namespace issue. The Transmission element is in no namespace, but you're selecting them with prefix `otm`.